# How to pass video as input to python code inside Android Studio

Tags: python-3.x, android-studio, chaquopy

I want to develop an application that can take video as input and then pass that video to the python code. I know that there is a python SDK named Chaquopy for using python code inside android studio. But I don't know how to take video from res folder inside Android Studio and pass that to python code. My main algorithm is in python and for that I need to pass video as input.
I'm new to android Studio. Can someone help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Chaquopy, the easiest way to load a file in Python code is to put it in the Python source code directory, not the res directory. From the [FAQ](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-data):

> If the data file is in the same directory as the Python file:
>
> ```
> from os.path import dirname, join
> filename = join(dirname(__file__), "filename.txt")
> You can then pass the filename to open, or any other function which reads a file.
> ```
>
> If the data file and the Python file are in different directories, then change the path accordingly. For example, if the Python file is `alpha/hello.py`, and the data file is `bravo/filename.txt`, then replace `filename.txt` above with `../bravo/filename.txt`.

Chaquopy doesn't currently provide any Python packages which can read video files directly. However, if you add [mobile-ffmpeg](https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg#22-android) to your project, you can call it from Python to extract the frames from the video, which you can then process however you like.

See [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/435#issuecomment-766089786) for a full example, and here are the relevant lines:

```
from com.arthenica.mobileffmpeg import FFmpeg
...
FFmpeg.execute("-i " + path + " -r " + frame_gap + " -f image2 " + initial_path + "/image-%2d.png")
image_read_counter = 1
while image_read_counter < int(vid_length_in_seconds * frame_gap):
    str_image_read_counter = '%02d' % image_read_counter
    image_path = initial_path + '/image-' + str_image_read_counter + '.png'
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    ...
```

Comment: So, If I want to capture video, then I should capture it through android java and store it in external storage. Then, through python code, i should access this video using moile-ffmpeg and process it. And if I don't want to capture it, I should place it in the same folder where I kept my python code. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, but it's better not to use external storage, because its permissions situation has become very complex in newer versions of Android. Use the [internal storage directory](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific) instead, which is accessible in Python as [`os.environ["HOME"]`](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#android-os).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have one more doubt. Will it be possible to do video processing while capturing the video? In Python, we can run our algorithms while capturing the video. Similarly, is it possible in android studio? If possible, how can I do it.

Comment: Yes, you can capture the video in Java/Kotlin and then pass the frames to Python as they arrive. In this case you don't need to store the frames in a file at all: just pass each one as a byte array. [Here](https://github.com/code-infinite/Helping-Hand-for-Divyajan) is an example of an app that does that.